# Timeseries histogram of data with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of documents organized as followed:

```
{
    "date": "2010-12-12" // Some valid datetime string
    "category": "some_category" // This can be any string
}
```

I need to create a frequency distribution for the data within buckets of time. I have looked at the [`date_histogram` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) but that only gets me halfway there.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "my_search" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "1s"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns me the count of my data that falls into all 1 second buckets. Within those 1 second buckets, I also need to aggregate all of the data into type `category` buckets, such that I'm left with buckets of time with counts of `category` within each bucket. Is there a built in method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path, you simply need to add another `terms` sub-aggregation for the `category` field:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "my_search" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "1s"
            }, 
            "aggs": {
                "categories": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "category"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an exception when I use this: 

            "type": "unknown_named_object_exception",
            "reason": "Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [categories]",

Comment: Do I have to define my other agg somewhere else?

Comment: My bad, bad copy/paste, try again please

Comment: Thanks Val, this is exactly what I wanted. Have a great day.